# Как сменить язык сообщений компилятора в Linux

Tags: linux, g++

Выглядит как машинный перевод:

```
…
settings.cpp: В функции-члене «void Settings::loadAndInit()»:
settings.cpp:73:5: предупреждение: эта «if» клаузула не защищает... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   73 |     if(restworker_ == nullptr)
      |     ^~
settings.cpp:75:9: замечание: ...этот оператор, но последний ошибочно полагается на защиту «if»
   75 |         mutex_.lock();
      |         ^~~~~~
…
```

Очень хочется при этом оставить русский во всех остальных приложениях.

Comment: `export LANG=C`

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо! Сейчас пользуюсь `export LANG=en` но хочется чтобы настройка была только для g++ а не для всей системы. Ну и не вводить заново в каждый терминал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Локаль, на которой `gcc` выводит свои сообщения контролиуется (в порядке глобальности) одной из следующих переменных среды: `LC_ALL`, `LANG` `LC_MESSAGES`. Соответственно получить английские сообщения можно, например запустив `gcc` как

```
LANG=C gcc ...
```

или  установив эту переменную глобально (это повлияет на сообщения всех програм):

```
export LANG=C
```

> Очень хочется при этом оставить русский во всех остальных приложениях.

Могу предложить несколько способов (некоторые из них могут быть несколько хачные):

1. Просто удалить локализацию. Обычно она находится в `/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/gcc-**.mo`. Её можно относительно безопасно просто удалить, но при обновлении пакета она снова появится.

   Также можно удалить сам пакет с локализацией. Обычно он называется как-то вроде `gcc-10-locales`.
2. Сделать обёртку для запуска компилятора (что-то вроде):

   В `~/bin/с-lang-wrap`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export LANG=C
   "$0" "$@"
   ```

   ---

   ```
   ln -s с-lang-wrap ~/bin/gcc
   ln -s с-lang-wrap ~/bin/g++
   ```

   И добавить `$HOME/bin` в начало `PATH`, например в `~/.profile`:

   export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
3. Использовать скрипт запуска компилятора средствами системы сборки, например в `cmake`:

   В `~/sh/с-lang-launcher`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export LANG=C
   "$@"
   ```

   При запуске `cmake`:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER="~/sh/с-lang-launcher" ...
   ```
4. Улучшить русскоязычные сообщения, чтобы не обязательно было переключаться на английский. Для `gcc` см. [TranslationProject](https://translationproject.org/html/welcome.html).

   Но стоит иметь в виду, что внутри, скорей всего, будет атмосфера специфической GNU'шно-FOSS'овской бюрократии, инструментарий и средства коммуникации родом из 90-х, а ответ на самое минимальное предложение может занимать недели и содержать отказ по формальным причинам, так что придётся набраться терпения.

Comment: FYI, в rpm-based дистрибутивах можно наконфигурировать систему, чтобы сам пакетный менеджер устанавливал только те переводы, которые хочется. В начале нулевых у меня на домашнем почтовом сервере катастрофически не хватало места, поэтому были выкинуты все переводы, man и документация на уровне настроек.

Comment: @0andriy, `dpkg` такое тоже умеет, но в данном случае оно не особо нужно…